# Hide button if you are on some page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I need to show two buttons created with `button_to` on some pages (Example: `list/id1/edit`) and hide one button on all other pages (Example: `list/new`). I have this:

```
= button_link t("list.save"), list_path(@list.save_id), class: "button"    
= button_link t("list.cancel"), list_path(@list.hashed_id), class: "button"
```

How can I create "if you are on page X show one button, else - 2 buttons"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like @arjun's answer (particularly with @RyanWilcox's comment), though just to throw something else into the ring, you'll also have access to the `controller_name` and `action_name` helpers...

i.e.

```
unless controller_name == 'list' && action_name == 'new'
  show_the_button
end
```

or

```
- unless controller_name == 'list' && action_name == 'new'
  = button_link t("list.save"), list_path(@list.save_id), class: "button"    
  = button_link t("list.cancel"), list_path(@list.hashed_id), class: "button"
```

That can be pretty flexible in terms of restricting / allowing certain controllers and / or actions.

Answer (score 4):

Please check this doc - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F

Use it as

`current_page?('http://www.example.com/shop/checkout')`

Comment: You would think you should be able to give this a path too: `current_page? shop_checkout_path`. Yay named routes...

Comment: I think yes, only if you have created that route in config/route.rb

Comment: indeed... yay for `$ rake routes` ;)